# translate drawing not moving to 0 position top and left

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm playing around with canvas and discovered an issue I don't understand when using the translate method.

In this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/claireC/ZJdus/4/, I would like the drawing to move and bounce off each of the four walls but the drawing will not move to the left wall or top wall. Here is the code I used for moving the drawing. This works for other drawings I've done but does not do the same for transform method.

```
if(dx < 0 || dx > 150) vx = -vx;
if(dy < 0 || dy > 240 ) vy = -vy;
```

What is it about translate method why this code does not work?

Comment: I think you forgot the actual fiddle link

Comment: I did, sorry. Here it is http://jsfiddle.net/claireC/ZJdus/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The drawing itself, which is relative to the translation never draws anything closer than 183 pixels from the edge for instance.

You need to compensate for this position as well, for example:

```
if(dx < -183 || dx > 150) vx = -vx;
if(dy < -87 || dy > 240 ) vy = -vy;
```

[image]

Origin is what you translate, drawing is drawn 183, 87 *relative* to origin.

**[Modified fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/ZJdus/6/)**

Alternatively change the drawing positions so that your drawing starts in the origin [0,0].

Comment: I see! I thought the origin of the drawing in default started at 0,0. Your explanation makes a lot more sense. Thanks.